# How to neatly association next and previous "node" within a tree structure?

Tags: algorithm, tree

Say I have a simple tree structure:

```
{
  label: 'a',
  children: [
    {
      label: 'a.a',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'a.a.a',
          children: [
            {
              label: 'a.a.a.a'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.a.a.b'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.a.a.c'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.a.a.d'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'a.a.b',
          children: [
            {
              label: 'a.a.b.a'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.a.b.b'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'a.a.c',
          children: [
            {
              label: 'a.a.c.a'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'a.a.d',
          children: [
            {
              label: 'a.a.d.a'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.a.d.b'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'a.b',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'a.b.a',
          children: [
            {
              label: 'a.b.a.a'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.b.a.b'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.b.a.c'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.b.a.d'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          label: 'a.b.b',
          children: [
            {
              label: 'a.b.b.a'
            },
            {
              label: 'a.b.b.b'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I neatly figure out `a.b.a.a` comes after `a.a.d.b` (`next`), and `a.b.a.d` comes before `a.b.b.a` (`previous`), for example?

That is, you go from leaf to leaf, even if the leaves aren't directly siblings. If they are siblings, you just go to the next/previous sibling, but if they are not siblings, you must navigate up and down the tree to find the next and previous ones.

What is a simple way to accomplish this? I have been at this for a bit and am stuck doing it in a non-hacky way. Basically I try doing itsy-bitsy incremental manual checks, like checking if the parent is a leaf, and if not, checking down, and then I get lost.

You can add a `.parent` property to keep track of the parent if that helps, or you can pass down the `path` (assume the label isn't actually the path as shown, that is just for illustrative purposes).

```
function linkNext(node) {
  const i = node.parent.indexOf(node)
  if (i < node.parent.children.length - 1) {
    node.next = node.parent.children[i + 1]
  } else {
    if (node.parent.parent) {
      // I get lost about here.
    }
  }
}

function linkPrevious(node) {
  const i = node.parent.indexOf(node)
  if (i > 0) {
    node.next = node.parent.children[i - 1]
  } else {
    // same here...
  }
}
```

Wondering how this can be done in a straightforward way, my mind gets tripped up on this problem.

Comment: [Level-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you may benefit from a *generator* function: it could yield the leaves in their order:

```
function* leaves(node) {
    if (!node.children) { // It's a leaf
        return yield node;
    }
    for (const child of node.children) {
        yield* leaves(child);
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can visit the leaves with a simple `for..of` loop:

```
for (const leaf of leaves(tree)) {
    console.log(leaf.label); 
}
```

To have the same in the reverse order, you could extend the generator with an optional argument:

```
function* leaves(node, reversed=false) {
    if (!node.children) { // It's a leaf
        return yield node;
    }
    const children = reversed ? node.children.toReversed() : node.children;
    for (const child of children) {
        yield* leaves(child, reversed);
    }
}
```

Maybe this is already enough for your purpose, but if you really want to add `next` properties to leaf nodes, then you could benefit from a function that would yield leaves together with their successors (as an array of two nodes). Here is a generic function to get that:

```
function* pairs(iterable) {
    const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    let prev = iterator.next().value;
    for (const next of iterator) {
        yield [prev, next];
        prev = next;
    }
}
```

And then the linking of leaves is as simple as:

```
for (const [prev, next] of pairs(leaves(tree, reversed))) {
    prev.next = next;
}
```

Here is all that put together, using your sample tree as input:

```js
function* leaves(node, reversed=false) {
    if (!node.children) { // It's a leaf
        return yield node;
    }
    const children = reversed ? node.children.toReversed() : node.children;
    for (const child of children) {
        yield* leaves(child, reversed);
    }
}

// Generic function to iterate the consecutive pairs of an iterable
function* pairs(iterable) {
    const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    let prev = iterator.next().value;
    for (const next of iterator) {
        yield [prev, next];
        prev = next;
    }
}

function linkNext(node, reversed=false) {
    for (const [prev, next] of pairs(leaves(tree, reversed))) {
        prev.next = next;
    }
}

// Example run
const tree = {label: 'a',children: [{label: 'a.a',children: [{label: 'a.a.a',children: [{label: 'a.a.a.a'},{label: 'a.a.a.b'},{label: 'a.a.a.c'},{label: 'a.a.a.d'}]},{
label: 'a.a.b',children: [{label: 'a.a.b.a'},{label: 'a.a.b.b'}]},{label: 'a.a.c',children: [{label: 'a.a.c.a'}]},{label: 'a.a.d',children: [{label: 'a.a.d.a'},{label: 'a.a.d.b'}]}]},{label: 'a.b',children: [{label: 'a.b.a',children: [{label: 'a.b.a.a'},{label: 'a.b.a.b'},{label: 'a.b.a.c'},{label: 'a.b.a.d'}]},{label: 'a.b.b',children: [{label: 'a.b.b.a'},{label: 'a.b.b.b'}]}]}]}

console.log("Iterate the leaves in their order:");
for (const node of leaves(tree)) console.log(node.label);
console.log("Iterate the leaves in reversed order");
for (const node of leaves(tree, true)) console.log(node.label);
// Set the next properties of leaves (only leaves!)
linkNext(tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to parse, but it looks like you need this:

```js
function linkTree(tree, precedingNode) {
    if (!tree) {
        return precedingNode;
    }
    if (tree.children) {
        // internal node -- no links
        for(child of tree.children) {
            precedingNode = linkTree(child, precedingNode);
        }
    } else {
        // leaves are linked into a doubly-linked list
        if (precedingNode) {
            tree.prev = precedingNode;
            precedingNode.next = tree;
        }
        precedingNode = tree;
    }
    return precedingNode;
}
```

Comment: It's not quite working as expected I don't think, it never sets the initial value so it always returns empty.

Comment: You call `linkTree(root,null)` on the root of the tree. The `precedingNode = tree` line should remember the first, and all following leaves, until the next `if (precedingNode)` that connects it to the next leaf.

Comment: Maybe your actual tree doesn't look like the example?